# What is the most natural way to say "But, with some caution"?

Tags: traduction, anglais

I'm thinking of phrases like, "Proceed, but with some caution." In this case, however, I want the standalone, "But, with some caution", as if the preceding sentence makes clear what the action should be. So far I have thought of two possibilities.

> Mais, avec une certaine prudence.
>
> Mais, avec quelque prudence.

Which would you prefer? Which sounds more natural?

Or would you choose an alternative?

Comment: Why do you want to add this comma after "but"? You don't have it in ""Proceed, but with some caution."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though *mais* is not commonly followed by a comma, it is possible to do it to mark a separation of some sort (hesitation, short reflexion, a brief pause to catch the full attention of the person to whom the message is intended). This [article from *la banque de dépannage linguistique*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3445) expands a bit more on the matter.

As far as your propositions go, both...

> Mais, avec une certaine prudence.
>   Mais, avec quelque prudence.

...work and sound native.

In a daily context, my natural tendency would probably be:

> Mais... prudemment!

***Mais,*** les gens ont différentes approches du vocabulaire !¹

Dropping the adjectives altogether also work (perhaps even more efficiently, since the only concept then invoked is the *caution*):

> Mais, avec prudence.

*¹ ...and many, even very different from each other, are equally valid.*

Answer (score 2):

We would simply say "mais avec prudence". 
I would rather translate by "avec précaution" or "en faisant attention".

Comment: Or "mais sois prudent"

Comment: Ah, those are good, but I think they lose a nuance from the English phrase. The phrase "some caution" has a slight twist... Much like, "Have fun, but be a little careful."

Comment: Ah ok, then maybe "amuse toi, mais reste (quand même ) prudent" ?